# Sub or Function undefined error when trying to concatenate multiple strings into one cell in VB

Tags: vba

I was trying to make a quick tool today at work to automate some tasks at work but ran into the problem of getting Sun or Function error. 
I am an absolute newbie in VB and not familiar with the syntax and or language specifics.
Could you please help me?
Details on what I a trying to do:
Basically, I have multiple groups(just 4 cells in each group) that I am trying to copy into single cell. Like this:

Group1:
cell1 
cell2
cell3
cell4

Group2:
.
.
.
Each one of those groups need to be copied into separate cells.

Here is the code:

```
Public Sub GlobalConcatenation()
    Dim sourcerange As Range
    Dim gbegin As Integer
    Dim gend As Integer
    gbegin = 2
    gend = 5
    sourcerange = Sheets("raw_LSToolData").Range(Cells(2, gbegin), Cells(2, gend))
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 2 To 50
        callConcatinateAllCellValuesInRange (sourcerange)

        sourcerange = Sheets("raw_LSToolData").Range(Cells(2, gbegin + 4), Cells(2, gend + 4))
End Sub
Function ConcatinateAllCellValuesInRange(sourcerange As Excel.Range) As String
    Dim finalValue As String

    Dim cell As Excel.Range

    For Each cell In sourcerange.Cells
        finalValue = finalValue + CStr(cell.Value)
    Next cell

    ConcatinateAllCellValuesInRange = finalValue
End Function
```

EDIT: I feel like I also need to specify that the problem shows up in GlobalConcatenation() function and whenever I get the error, "sourcerange" is being highlighted.

EDIT: updated the code - fixed spelling mistake

Comment: `sourcerange` appears in your code multiple times. So which line is execution actually breaking on? Also, there seem to be a few other typos/misspellings in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to spell mistake on this line at `gbeging`:-

**Wrong One:-**

```
sourcerange = Sheets("raw_LSToolData").Range(Cells(2, gbeging), Cells(2, gend))

sourcerange = Sheets("raw_LSToolData").Range(Cells(2, gbeging + 4), Cells(2, gend + 4))
```

**Correct One:-**

```
sourcerange = Sheets("raw_LSToolData").Range(Cells(2, gbegin), Cells(2, gend))

sourcerange = Sheets("raw_LSToolData").Range(Cells(2, gbegin + 4), Cells(2, gend + 4))
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but the problem still persists.

Comment: @GKED: Now what the error message you are getting. Where you are assigning the value of `callConcatinateAllCellValuesInRange (sourcerange)`?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely cause of your error is the unqualified references to cells in the lines like

```
sourcerange = Sheets("raw_LSToolData").Range(Cells(2, gbegin), Cells(2, gend))
```

`Cells(2, gbegin)` refers to a cell on the active sheet.  If this is not `raw_LSToolData` an error will result

The correct code is

```
sourcerange = Sheets("raw_LSToolData").Range(Sheets("raw_LSToolData").Cells(2, gbegin), Sheets("raw_LSToolData").Cells(2, gend))
```

A better way is

```
with Sheets("raw_LSToolData")
    sourcerange = .Range(.Cells(2, gbegin), .Cells(2, gend))
end with
```

Note the `.`'s before `Range` and `Cells` - this references the `with` clause object